Could HttpOnly cookie be accessed in browser by malicious JS
In the Backend-For-Frontend (BFF) description here. The last sentence in the section caught my concern, it says:

Since the malicious JavaScript code still runs within the
application's origin, the attacker is able to send requests to the BFF
from within the user's browser (Proxying Requests via the User's
Browser (Section 5.1.4))

Then, I checked the "Section 5.1.4" mentioned there.
I hope I understand it correctly, but does it mean, even the access tokens are handled by BFF instead of the browser side, but the session cookie is sent to frontend in browser, even we flag the cookie with HttpOnly, there still could be malicious Javascript in browser be able to access it and use the cookie to access BFF which then use the associated access token to access other resource services?  If so, doesn't it loose the benefit of BFF since the secure cookie can be intercepted & token is misused still?

The malicious JS won't be able to read the cookie value on the client side, due to it being HttpOnly - but if the malicious request is able to cause a request to the BFF, then the cookie will of course get sent along with that request.

@C3roe are you referring to CSRF attack?

CSRF is rather an attack from the outside; if a script gets embedded directly into your site, that wouldn't really qualify, IMHO.

@C3roe just to make sure, in your 1st comment, the scenario you described, I understand the cookie will send along with that malicious request, but could you please elaborate in practice how that malicious request is possible? I am not doubting but just want to understand more concretely. Where could that kind of request come from? Thanks.

From the malicious JS code, that somehow got injected into your site. The whole paragraph starts with "If an attacker is able to execute malicious code within the JavaScript application [...]"

@C3roe, so is the fundamental concern the same as in CSRF that the malicious request (either from outside or inside) impersonating a legitimate request to the server along with the cookie which could mutate resource data?     Do you agree here?

That would be the "proxy" scenario then, I think. https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps#scenario-proxy

@C3roe, true, that's exactly what I meant regarding to the harm it could possibly cause with the malicious requests which are indistinguishable in backend. What could be the measures to reduce this attack surface?  CSRF token could be an option, are there other effective ways?

Not sure how exactly a CRSF token would help, when the request is made by injected JavaScript. That would likely either have access to the token as well (if it gets stored anywhere in the DOM, or a non-HttpOnly cookie); or it would get send along same as any other cookie, if it was stored in an HttpOnly cookie.

@C3roe, do you mean there is no viable way to reduce the risk of that from happening?

Other than that you prevent malicious scripts from running in your site as best as possible in the first place - probably not.

Yes - HttpOnly cookies can be abused by malicious JavaScript in an XSS attack. This has always been true in websites also:

An attacker can steal your data using your cookie credential - sometimes called session-riding.

Note that this is not the same as CSRF, which is relatively easy to defend against.
The browser is an imperfect environment. The best you can do is:

Use HttpOnly cookies to transport access tokens
Use SameSite=strict (and CORS in some setups) to deny cookie access to malicious sites or origins
Set a strong CSP to help prevent data being exfiltrated
Take standard measures to prevent XSS in the first place

You then limit the impact of exploits as Philippe De Ryck explains in the link you provide. Such threats end if the user closes the browser for example.
Whereas tokens in the browser might be exfiltrated (especially if the CSP is disabled) and used for a more concerted attack against your APIs, that continues after the user closes the browser.
